# finish() not working

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a rather strange behavior of my application. I am starting my app after BOOT_COMPLETE, hence it is visible after I booted the device. The GUI is responsive and everything is working fine, until I call finish(), when pressing a button, then nothing happens. The GUI is still responsive and no ANR nor suspicious logcat message is produced, so I have no hint.

So far I tried:

- Attached the debugger and followed the calls, but I could not find anything
- I checked the running instance of the activity (with the eclipse memory analyzer), and there is just one in Memory
- I suspended the launch, for some seconds and  finish() worked fine ( this is my current workaround)

Well unfortunately there is no useful code to post in order to demonstrate this problem, because everything is working fine, when launching the Activity at any later point in time.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

I am running Android 2.1 on an Samsung Device, and I tested it on Android 2.2 on an HTC Desire, but this error did not happen on an Nexus 4 and also not on the Emulator, maybe it is device/version specific.

**EDIT**
This is the Activity Manifest Entry

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:immersive="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"

             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Is this device specific?  Same behavior in the emulator?

Comment: Well difficult to tell, I could not reproduce the boot_complete behavior, so I really don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Why is your Activity disabled? From the Android docs:

> android:enabled- Whether or not the activity can be instantiated by
>   the system — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. The default
>   value is "true".

This might have confused the system and when you called finish it only saw that the Actvity is disabled, try making it true.

Comment: Well this is unfortunately not the issue (I removed it for testing reasons).